# throttle concurrent builds on docker host machine through Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a fully dockerized build environment where feature branch builds are being triggered with a scripted Jenkinsfiles.  Here is the simplified environment.

Machine-A builds all versions for product-A but has only enough resources to do two builds in parallel.  A docker image exists for building each version of product-A as the tools used vary from version to version.

A feature branch is pushed with a scripted Jenkinsfile.  That Jenkinsfile specifies the version number (v1) being built and hence specifies programmatically that a specific docker image is used for building v1.

The same then occurs for v2. This will cause another docker container to be launched to build v2.

When a feature branch arrives for v3, there are no long sufficient resources.

How can I limit the number of concurrent builds/docker containers being run on the host machine through a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: From Jenkins, there is no clean solution yet the [issue][1] is still open. 


  [1]: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44141

Comment: Thanks Ram.  It helps knowing others have the need as well

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my issue was to use lockable resources.
https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources

Work perfectly for my needs